# Menu shortcut overrides NSTextField's normal behavior

Tags: cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, nstextfield

In my cocoa app I have a Menu to "select all" and I naturally assign "Command-A" to it.

However if I am in a text field and I press Command-A, instead of selecting all the text in the text field it calls the menu. How can I overcome this?

I have tried subclassing NSTextField to have `becomeFirstResponder` return true but that didn't work out.

EDIT: Select All is "mine" and is not in the Edit menu. Its "Sent Action" points at the first responder (which is a red herring). I'm not sure how Save is done (how it ends up calling my NSDocument because it also refers to First Responder). 
Instead of First Responder I moved the menu's action to the App Delegate (which then tries to get the current NSDocument and do its stuff) but it is still not working.
What should I point the action at? Looks like I only have the choice between "Application", "App Delegate" and "First Responder".

Comment: How is the Select All menu item implemented? Did you replace the default Select All in the Edit menu? What are the target and selector of your Select All menu item?

Comment: @Willeke thanks for chiming in. I updated the question with more details

Comment: The target should be the first responder (`nil` in code) and the action should be `selectAll:`, just like the default Select All in the Edit menu. See [First Responders](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW24) in Cocoa Event Handling Guide.

Comment: @Willeke thanks, this works for getting the text field select all its text, but how do I retrieve the menu action when there is no text field? I tried to add `-(void) selectAll:(id) sender` on my view controller, window controller, app delegate, and document, but it never got called. Am I supposed to turn on and off this thing as the text field gets and loses the focus?

Comment: Which control is focused when the text field isn't? Is a table view or collection view catching select all?

Comment: @Willeke that was it thanks. a table view had the focus and when I added `selectAll:` on it it was called. I will take it from there. Thanks a lot!